# Calling Python script from Winform C# Application

Tags: c#, python-3.x, winforms, process, ironpython

I want to call a Python script from my winform C# application. I checked for some solutions and followed following approaches. One using Inter-Process communication and one using IronPython

Approach 1 : Using Inter-Process Communication

```
private void BtnSumPy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string python = @"C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe";

        // python app to call 
        string myPythonApp = @"C:\mypath\\SamplePy\SamplePy2\SamplePy2.py";

        // dummy parameters to send Python script 
        int x = 3;
        int y = 4;

        // Create new process start info 
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);

        // make sure we can read the output from stdout 
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        // start python app with 3 arguments  
        // 1st arguments is pointer to itself,  
        // 2nd and 3rd are actual arguments we want to send 
        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + x + " " + y;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        // assign start information to the process 
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

        // start the process 
        myProcess.Start();

        // Read the standard output of the app we called.  
        // in order to avoid deadlock we will read output first 
        // and then wait for process terminate: 
        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

        /*if you need to read multiple lines, you might use: 
            string myString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd() */

        // wait exit signal from the app we called and then close it. 
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.Close();           

        lblAns.Text = myString;
    }
```

The issue with above approach is that Python.exe will have to installed on the local machines as well, as winform app is going to run locally on the system.

Approach 2: Using IronPython

```
private void BtnJsonPy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1. Create Engine
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

        //2. Provide script and arguments
        var script = @"C:\Users\simeh\source\HDFC\repos\SamplePy\SamplePy2\SamplePy2.py"; // provide full path
        var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(script);

        // dummy parameters to send Python script 
        int x = 3;
        int y = 4;

        var argv = new List<string>();
        argv.Add("");
        argv.Add(x.ToString());
        argv.Add(y.ToString());

        engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);

        //3. redirect output
        var eIO = engine.Runtime.IO;

        var errors = new MemoryStream();
        eIO.SetErrorOutput(errors, Encoding.Default);

        var results = new MemoryStream();
        eIO.SetOutput(results, Encoding.Default);

        //4. Execute script
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();

        var lib = new[]
        {
            "C:\\path\\SamplePy\\packages\\IronPython.2.7.9\\lib",
            "C:\\path\\SamplePy\\packages\\IronPython.2.7.9",
        };

        engine.SetSearchPaths(lib);
        engine.ExecuteFile(script, scope);
        //source.Execute(scope);

        //5. Display output
        string str(byte[] x1) => Encoding.Default.GetString(x1);

        Console.WriteLine("Errrors");
        Console.WriteLine(str(errors.ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Results");
        Console.WriteLine(str(results.ToArray()));
    }
```

The issue I get here is that I keep getting errors like 'Json module error' or 'PIL module error'

I read somewhere that PIL won't currently work with IronPython because it uses a native C library.

The python script has ML logic and uses OCR etc., for image processing and hence requires PIL, which cannot be done in IronPython.

So any better approach or ways or suggestions on how to call Python script from Winform C# application.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here for 'import error' open the cmd and go to the AppData>Local>Programs>Python>Python37-32 then write this

```
pip3 install json
```

if u wanna run .py file from c# the import modules must be in the directory of python.exe

for example ı imported the cv2 and the others libs to Python37-32 dir. After this my program worked fine.

This is my code:

```
timer1.Enabled = true;
                    progressBar1.Value += 10;
                    string myPythonApp = "C://Users//giris//Desktop//staj_proje_son//main.py";
                    string cmdArguments = "/c \"python " + myPythonApp + " " + "--ogrencioptik " + textBox2.Text + " " + "--cevapkagidi " + textBox1.Text + " " + "--sonuckayit " + textBox3.Text + "\"";
                    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    start.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    start.UseShellExecute = false;
                    start.WorkingDirectory = "C://Users//giris//Desktop//staj_proje_son//";
                    start.Arguments = cmdArguments;
                    start.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                    start.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    start.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    Process process = Process.Start(start);
                    timer1.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    timer1.Stop();
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    progressBar1.Value = 100;
                    MessageBox.Show("İşlem Bitti");
                    button3.Enabled = true;
```

Note:
All the textbox.text is the path for a folder.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution. I am yet to try. But just how we can write "pip3 install json", can we do the same to install 'PIL' module as well, or it is not yet supported with existing IronPython module?.

Comment: u can use whatever like pip install Pillow. just be in the pyhon.exe directory :) install the modules inside this dir. then try my code you will see it will work fine

Comment: Also above code is for inter-process communication, which is working fine for me. Module error is coming if I use IronPython 2.7.9 in my winforms app.

Comment: import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\Lib\\")   

on IronPython when ı wrote this in my .py file ı solved the problrem can u try this ?

Comment: I have added Nuget Package for IronPython, so the only path reference I get is from my solution project folder path "C:\\project-path\\SamplePy\\packages\\IronPython.2.7.9\\lib"
So do I add the modules here?. I am just new hence many questions.

Comment: That is your right to ask questions we are in stacoverflow u are welcome :) yes only create the modules to IronPython>Lib

Comment: As said I have added IronPython as Nuget package. When trying to run pip3 install json from the project folder path in command prompt it tells, pip3 is not recognized command.
Should I download IronPython first on machine?.
Or should I copy json folder inside Python.exe Lib folder to IronPython folder?.

Comment: try pip install not pip3 if it doesnt work try python -m pip install pillow if this doesnt work too look at this link https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/a2xusa/pip3_is_not_recognized_as_an_internal_or_external/

Comment: Should I install IronPython separately from "https://ironpython.net/download/" and then install the necessary modules on the path where IronPython was saved, and then use these references inside my code?.
Will this approach work fine?.